# Selfcontained non executable jar with maven

Tags: java, maven

We have created a test fixture containing functions used by our automated tests (Fitnesse based). I would like to package this fixture so it contains all it dependencies as the main test source doesn't have to copy all the transitive dependencies to work.

Have found some assembly examples but they all crate two jars, one with and one without transitive deps.

How can I build a *single* jar containing all the deps?

Comment: Why do you mean? Assembly `package-single` will, by default, create a `jar` called `jar-with-dependencies` in addition to the original build artefact. After installing these two artefacts you simply need to import the appropriate dependency with the classifier `with-dependencies` into the other project. The fact that there are two build artefacts shouldn't bother you.

Comment: You can create a uber jar with maven by using `shade` plugin :https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/